# CakeResque not loading model

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0, scheduler

I'm using http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/usage to create backend jobs in Cakephp.

My current setup is this :

app/Console/Command/AppShell.php

```
//AppShell.php

App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class AppShell extends Shell
{

    public function perform()
    {
        $this->initialize();
        $this->loadTasks();
        $this->{array_shift($this->args)}();
    }

}
```

and file : app/Console/Command/UserShell.php

```
//UserShell.php
    App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');
App::uses('User', 'Model');
class UserShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses = array('User');

    public function changePasswords(){

        $users = $this->User->fetchAll();
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But every time I get to the $this->User->fetchAll(); I get an error

```
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

I tried loading up the model in many ways, the database config is correct, because the main site is working normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it works when you try executing the changePassword() method via the cake shell ?

Comment: Sry for the response coming a month later, but I didn't notice that anyone responded.

When I run the command from bash I get the same response. A simple hello world output to console works, but with models it gives the same error as mentioned above

Comment: It's likely an issue with your CLI environment. Check that the mysql extension is loaded in your cli php.ini

Comment: You were right, I had 2 php installations, one was in my /opt/lampp/bin/ and the other one was in /etc/php/. The one in xampp was properly configured, so I just pointed the link from /usr/bin/php to /etc/lampp/bin/php and everything works fine. 

Tnx for the insight :D